# Dialog that saves a particular user filepath - Xcode

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, dialog

How can i show a dialog that just can be used to save a filepath to a string, filepath that the user chose with the dialog?
I searched around and i can only find open dialog and save dialog. I need something like the save file dialog, but i don't need the "save as" stuff
Thanks

Comment: What do yo mean you don't need the "save as" stuff? If you want, you can customize (to some extent) the text of the `NSSavePanel`. In any case, that is what you want to use.

Comment: for example: http://libcinder.org/docs/welcome/mac_images/newprojsave.png i don't need the top bar ("save as:"). i just need the main window (path browser) and the OK button ("save")

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the user to pick a file name, you just want them to pick an existing folder? If so, then use the `NSOpenPanel` with `canChooseFiles` set to `NO` and `canChooseDirectories` set to `YES.

Comment: that's what i was looking for! make an answer so i can vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you don't want the user to pick a file name, you just want them to pick an existing folder? If so, then use the `NSOpenPanel` with `canChooseFiles` set to `NO` and `canChooseDirectories` set to `YES`.